# How can I fire an event when focusing on a form in an iframe using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm building an application using jQuery. This application has a form and I want to know when a user focuses on any one of the fields in the form by firing an event. Sounds easy? Only problem - the form is in an iframe which means I can use the standard `$( "input" ).focus(function() {})` type selector.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this using jQuery *or* vanilla Javascript?

Edit: The content is on the same page

Comment: Is the content of the iframe on the same domain as the outer page?

Comment: If the content is on the same domain, create a custom event on the main page, and trigger it from the focus listeners on the iframed page.